# How to force FujiFilm X-T1 to use flash in automatic mode?

Tags: flash, fujifilm

I want my X-T1 to use flash when in automatic mode, for example when taking [back-lit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contre-jour) photos.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Philosophical question of the day: If one overrides the automatic mode then is one actually using automatic mode ??

Comment: Nothing that far. I use the automatic mode, but at times I would like to use the flash against the sun (we say "détourer une ombre" in French). Whatever the mode I choose, the flash does not run on my X-T1. So, my question is: what do I have to do to get my flash flashes?

Comment: What flash unit are you using?

Answer (score 1):

- On X-series cameras without built-in flash, you will need to attach a compatible flash unit.  Make sure it is turned on with fully charged batteries.
- On X-series cameras with built-in flash, you can press the appropriate button to release the pop-up flash.

Then in the quick settings menu, scroll to the desired flash mode (lightning icon).

If the flash still does not work, consult the flash unit and camera manuals.

Comment: It's a little more intricated - - X-T1 software try to act smart and does not flash just because the photographer asks it to do. So my question is "how can I tell my X-T1 to flash whatever its current mode?"